# How much time does it take to zero-out hard disk of 500gb?

Tags: hard-drive, badblocks

I'm seeing a blank screen with cursor(underscore) at the top left. My laptop is accessing the hard disk continously. It's been around 15 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

What command did you use?  Just for the record, if you used dd without specifying a block size, it will take an eternity.  If you specify a decent block size, it goes quicker.

That said, it depends on so many factors that it's impossible to give you a decent answer.  (For example: Disk speed, interface type, whether there are errors on the disk, ...)

My first question is: why do you want to zero it out?  If it's for your own use, just repartition.  If you want to trash the disk, the most efficient way is to use a nice big hammer on the disk until its heavily damaged.  That should stop most amateurs getting any data from it.

Comment: It had bad sectors in it. I was getting warning that disk may fail soon. So, I thought clearing it and installing OS will be good.

Comment: Nope.
Trying to repair a disk that way is playing with fire, if it works at all.

The disk is good for the trashbin.  That's it.  Do yourself a favour and get rid of it.

Comment: @user3664868 the warning that the disk may fail soon refers to the hardware itself. Writing to it even more will just make it worse.

Comment: Okay. I see your point. I will buy a new one. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

The last time I did this before selling a disc a couple of years ago, dd-ing with a 4086 byte buffer and appropriate numbers for the size of the disk, I was getting 2-3 GB/minute (there's a dd option for getting occasional progress reports, though I forget the details). So a 500GB disc would take around 200 minutes or 3 and a bit hours.

Remember, you've got to generate 500GB of data (that it's all "0" doesn't matter), then write it to the disc. If you're on a USB-2 connector, for example, you'll be limited to 480MB/sec, and 500GB @ 0.48GB/sec is a thousand seconds (18 minutes) even with nothing else happening at all.

Comment: It took almost 3-4 hrs and finally ended with an error that says like it was able to do 279gb to zero with speed of 25.9mb/s and input/output read,write error. I don't remember exactly but it was something like that.

Comment: You are mixing up bits and bytes.  USB2 is 480Mbit/sec...  1Byte=8bits, so theoretical transfer rate of USB is 60MByte/sec.   That's totally ignoring overhead.  60MByte/s means 0.06GByte/s, which means for 500GBbyte, you need 8333 seconds, also known as 2 hours and 20 minutes.

Calculate in overhead and it starts getting closer to the actual results that user3664868 had.  (It also matches your stated experience)

Comment: Oh, and another detail.  You most likely meant a buffer of 4096 bytes, which is (for this task) frankly... not enough.  That's basically one sector, which won't help you that much.

Just give it a bigger buffer.  You've got enough memory, right.  I usually use bs=1G and let it work.  Too small buffer sizes with dd aren't helping as much as you'd think.

Comment: Ooops, yes. Bits & bytes.
Never bothered to experiment with buffer sizes much. Once I'd got something that was working OK (IIRC I did the trick of sending the dd process a signal from another terminal to force a status report), I could leave it working in a corner of the office and get on with paying work.